# Laravel Paginate with OrderBy

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

When querying a product code table I have the following

```
$results = Stock::orderBy('stk_physical', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

This works fine on the initial load of 10 records but when a subsequent call is made for page 2 I get the following error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'offset'. (SQL: select * from [stock_records] order by [stk_physical] desc offset 10 rows fetch next 10 rows only)
```

I'm using Laravel 8.0 with SQL

Comment: what is the database you are using ?

Comment: I’m using SQL on a 2019 instance

Comment: you mean sql server ?

Comment: Yes I'm using SQL server

Comment: can you take a look at the PR https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/39863

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should append query string to the pagination like this

```
$results = Stock::orderBy('stk_physical', 'desc')->paginate(10);

$results->appends(["order_by" => "stk_physical"]);
```

This will append the `&order_by=stk_physical` to each link in the view and you can also use `withQueryString()` to take in consideration query string in future pagination like this

```
$results = Stock::orderBy('stk_physical', 'desc')->paginate(10)->withQueryString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried appending the order_by parameter but I still get an Offset error. Paginate seems to work fine on MySQL but I'm using SQL.